Chern classes and rational equivalence
Let $X$ be a complex variety and let $l_1$ and $l_2$ be line bundles on $X$. Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be sections of $l_1$ and $l_2$ respectively, and let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ be their zero-sets.
I would like to know about the relationship between the following conditions:

$Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are rationally equivalent

$l_1$ and $l_2$ have the same Chern classes

$l_1 \cong l_2$ and $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are rationally equivalent (edit: looks like this should be just that $l_1 \cong l_2$)



There are two different definitions of the Chern class in algebraic geometry. It can be defined both as a cohomology class and as an algebraic cycle class. The answer to your question is different in the two cases.

We have $l_1 \cong l_2$ if and only if $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are rationally equivalent. The Chern class in the sense of algebraic cycles is $Z_1$, respectively, $Z_2$, so if we consider cycles up to rational equivalence the condition that $l_1$ and $l_2$ have the same Chern class is also equivalent to the others. The Chern class in the sense of cohomology is merely the cohomology class of $Z_1$, respectively, $Z_2$, so those being the same is a weaker condition.

@WillSawin Thanks very much for your answer! Since posting I notice that the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem for cohomology with coefficients in ??? seems related. But also, if the Chern class is a complete invariant on line bundles, then doesn't that imply that the second bullet in the above is also equivalent to the (recently modified) third?

Yes, your last sentence is true.

@WillSawin Thanks Professor Sawin you're the best!

Can whoever downvoted explain why?

@RonZ. You do not have to care much about downvotes — people vote down the question when they dislike, and it is sometimes irrelevant to whether the question is interesting or not.
